# (Possible) Memory leak with custom ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, kotlin

To centralize background thread handling in my Android app, I've defined the following `Runnable`:

```
class Task(private val runnable: Runnable) : Runnable {

    interface Callback {
        fun onTaskStarted()
        fun onTaskFinished()
    }

    var callback: Callback? = null

    override fun run() {
        callback?.run { mainHandler.post { this.onTaskStarted() } }
        runnable.run()
        callback?.run { mainHandler.post { this.onTaskFinished() } }

        // setting callback to null, so the Task instance can be garbage collected
        callback = null
    }

    companion object {
        private val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    }
}
```

And the following `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
class CustomThreadPoolExecutor :
        ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()),
        Task.Callback {

    val taskCount: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { value = 0 }
    }

    fun executeTask(task: Task) {
        task.callback = this
        super.execute(task)
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun onTaskStarted() {
        taskCount.value = taskCount.value?.plus(1) ?: 1
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun onTaskFinished() {
        taskCount.value = taskCount.value?.minus(1) ?: 0
    }
}
```

The latter is a singleton provided by *Dagger*:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideCustomThreadPoolExecutor(): CustomThreadPoolExecutor = CustomThreadPoolExecutor()
```

The idea is to use this executor for all background tasks.

The `taskCount` object can be observed and for example show/hide a `ProgressBar` based on if there are tasks running currently or not.

The `taskCount` object is accessed only from the main thread, so there shouldn't be any concurrency issues (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The `callback` is the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance itself (which is a singleton) and the reference is cleared as soon as the task is finished, so this shouldn't be a problem either (again, please correct me if I'm wrong).

**The problem:**

To insert data into my database, I'd call the following method of my `Activity` (or `Fragment`)

```
private fun saveTestData(testItems: List<TestItem>) {
    customThreadPoolExecutor.executeTask(Task(Runnable {
        testService.saveAll(testItems)
    }))
}
```

The `Runnable` here is an anonymous inner class and thus (I think) holds a reference to the enclosing `Activity` (or `Fragment`).

Because of this, the `Runnable` (and the wrapping `Task`) cannot be garbage collected, so every time I call this method the instance count will grow (and never shrink).

Are my assumptions correct?

If so, how could I solve this problem?

(Java answers are welcome as well)

Comment: Why would the instance be retained indefinitely? After it's executed, it's gone

Comment: Second thing, it's a bad idea to subclass `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Kotlin has a first-class feature for the [Delegation pattern](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thank you for your reply. So other than the subclassing, do you think this is a viable concept? Or do you see any other flaws?

Comment: If this was my project, I'd replace all this with coroutines. I would need almost no support code to achieve it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: Very simple example: `this.launch { initialStuff(); val result = withContext(MyThreadPool) { networkOperation() }; updateGui(result) }`. Here `this` should be your activity or a fragment that implements `CoroutineScope`. It gives you automatic cancellation of all background tasks if the activity is destroyed.